# Why can we rewrite $x^{k + 1} - y^{k + 1}$ as $x^{k + 1} - x^ky - y^{k + 1}$ in math induction?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction

In an exercise, I had to prove by induction that $(x^n-y^n)$ is divisible by $(x-y)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But I don't understand one of the algebraic manipulation, and to give you more context, here's the given solution:

> Solution:
>
> Let the given statement be P(n). Then,
>
> P(n): $(x^n - y^n)$ is divisible by $(x - y)$.
>
> When $n = 1$, the given statement becomes: $(x^1 - y^1)$ is divisible by $(x-y)$, which is clearly true.
>
> Therefore P(1) is true.
>
> Let p(k) be true. Then,
>
> P(k): $x^k - y^k$ is divisible by $(x-y)$.
>
> Now, $x^{k + 1}$ - $y^{k + 1}$ = $x^{k + 1}$ - $x^ky$ - $y^{k + 1}$
>
> ```
>                           [on adding and subtracting x)ky]
> ```
>
> = ${x^k}(x - y) + y(x^k - y^k)$, which is divisible by (x - y) [using (i)]
>
> ⇒ P$(k + 1)$: $x^{k + 1} - y^{k + 1}$ is divisible by $(x-y)$
>
> ⇒ P$(k + 1)$ is true, whenever P(k) is true.
>
> Thus, P(1) is true and P$(k + 1)$ is true, whenever P(k) is true.
>
> Hence, by the Principal of Mathematical Induction, P(n) is true for
> all n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

I don't understand why $x^{k + 1} - y^{k + 1} = x^{k + 1} - x^ky - y^{k + 1}$, like why is it that we can transform it like that, because where does "$- x^ky$" come from?

I'm also very sorry if it's unclear, so  here is the link for the exercise:
https://www.math-only-math.com/proof-by-mathematical-induction.html

And it should be the  5th example. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

It is a typo.

The following equality is clearly false unless $x=0$ or $y=0$:
$$x^{k + 1} - y^{k + 1} = x^{k + 1} - x^ky - y^{k + 1}.$$
Not only is that equality blatantly false, but it's not consistent with what follows in the proof.

The intended equality was:
$$x^{k + 1} - y^{k + 1} = x^{k + 1} - x^ky + x^ky - y^{k + 1}.$$

Comment: One minute. I only needed one more minute… (+1)

Comment: Ha thank you so much! This is exactly how I wrote it when trying to solve this exercise, quite reassuring!